# How to use $wind for adding list value in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb

I have my mongodb document structure as shown below:

```
{

    "_id" : NumberLong(366),

    "_class" : "com.cts.adpart.domain.DBData",

    "curatorList" : [

            {

                    "_id" : NumberLong(0),

                    "userBI" : "2",

            }

    ]

}
```

I have to sum the userBI values from all documents in a collection and display the result

I have tried the below query but it is always returning 0

```
db.collection.aggregate[ {$unwind: "$curatorList"},{$group : {_id : null , sum: {$sum:"$curatorList.userBI"} } } ]
```

Can anyone help me with the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field value is string "2", change it to 2 and your query is going to work.